# Array not being parsed correctly

Tags: php, arrays

Having issues with an array being parsed..

Here is a dump from the $_GET var

```
Array
(
    [perm0] => Array
        (
            [0] => View
            [1] => Add
            [2] => Edit
            [3] => Delete
            [4] => Export
        )

    [perm1] => Array
        (
            [0] => View
            [1] => Add
            [2] => Export
        )

    [add] => 
)
```

When I try and use a foreach to insert into the db its only inserting the first item.
I am need to add the number based on the perm[] value such as perm0, perm1 etc

Here is my code

```
$i = 0;
$id = 0;
     foreach($_GET['perm'.$i] as $permission)
        {
           do {
                $perms = implode(":",$_GET['perm'.$i]);
                mysqli_query($dbc,"INSERT INTO `permissions` (`mid`,`uid`,`permissions`) VALUES ('$id','99','$perms')");
                echo mysqli_error($dbc);    
              } while(strpos($permission, $i) !== false);
          $id++;
          $i++;
        }
```

I would have thought this would be really simple so I dont know why I'm having issues with it

Comment: [from comments] _“There are other form fields so that wouldnt work hence the $_GET['perm'.$i]”_ - that could be fixed by naming the form fields differently … `name="perm[0][]"`, `name="perm[1][]"`, and you get a multi-dimensional array in `$_GET['perm']` that you can foreach over without having to assemble the proper access key yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are always only looking at the first item, your statement...

```
foreach($_GET['perm'.$i] as $permission)
```

will only ever pick up the `perm0` item, even though you increment `$i` in the loop.

Instead, this code loops over all `$_GET` values, checks if they are the `permN` values and then inserts the value.  I've also converted to prepared statements to add some level of security...

```
$i = 0;
$insert = mysqli_prepare ($dbc,"INSERT INTO 
            `permissions` (`mid`,`uid`,`permissions`) 
             VALUES (?,'99',?)");
foreach ( $_GET as $key => $param ) {
    if ( $key == "perm$i" ) {
        $perms = implode(":",$param);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param ($insert, "is", $i, $perms);
        mysqli_execute($insert);
        $i++;
    }
}
```

As it's difficult for me to test this, please let me know if you have issues.